# Cassandra not able to start : UnknownHostException

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

When I try to run the below command in dse in throw UnknownHostExcpetion,

> ./dse cassandra

**Exceptiom**

ERROR [main] 2018-04-23 15:36:39,630  CassandraDaemon.java:723 - Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: jarvis: jarvis: Temporary failure in name resolution

Answer (score 0):

You referenced to the `jarvis` as host name somewhere in `cassandra.yaml` config file. You need to make sure that this name is resolvable - run `nslookup jarvis` to see that it resolves to IP

Comment: Server:  127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find jarvis: SERVFAIL
It shows above message, what has to be done now ?

Comment: it looks like that your DNS isn't configured correctly. I recommend to use IP addresses instead of names

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why it throws the error. I started the cassandra using `./dse cassandra` command. But I didn't even stopped the cassandra and I shutdowned my system. When I tried to start cassandra for the next time it shows me **java.net.UnknownHostException**. Command to stop cassandra is `./dse cassandra-stop`, when I ran command to stop and started for the next time it worked perfectly.